# Rails + Devise returning duplicate set-cookie response headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, setcookie

I'm using Devise + Devise JWT with on API-only instance of Rails (7.0.2). We are using secure-cookies to pass our auth token to the frontend and noticed that the response we get after signing in has duplicate `set-cookie` headers. One of the tokens is incorrect/old and it's causing issues on our front-end.

I'm not sure where to even start or pick apart how the middleware is setting this. Has anyone experienced this, or any pointers on what devise methods I can inspect where this is being set? Are both Rails and Devise trying to set their own secure set-cookie?

Some of my secure-cookie config below:

In `config/initializers/devise.rb` I have:

```rb
...

config.rememberable_options = { secure: true }
```

`config/initializers/session_store.rb`

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_session_id', secure: true
```

`config/application.rb`:

```rb
...
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```rb
include ActionController::Cookies
include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection

before_action :set_csrf_cookie

protect_from_forgery with: :exception

...

private

def set_csrf_cookie
  cookies['CSRF-TOKEN'] = form_authenticity_token
end
```

Below is a screenshot from Postman of the `set-cookie` headers we are getting back
[image: set-cookie header response]

Versions:

```
Rails 7.0.2.2
Ruby 3.0.3
devise 4.8.1
Devise-jwt 0.9.0
```

Any help/pointers appreciated

Comment: did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @cdimitroulas nope, never found an answer and moved away from secure cookies

Comment: In my case it was a duplicate cookie store middleware. Do you need both of those middleware in your `config/application.rb`? Not sure you are experiencing the same issue as I was